# Multiselect Box with Optgroups: Select one per group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select, drop-down-menu

I have a selectbox with the `multiple` attribute set.  I'm also using `<optgroup>` tags to separate categories within my select box.  I'm looking for a way, using either javascript or jQuery, to have the various options within each group to behave with 'radio button logic' rather than 'check box logic'.  For example:

```
<optgroup label="cat1">
    <option>item 1.1</option>
    <option>item 1.2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="cat2">
    <option>item 2.1</option>
    <option>item 2.2</option>
</optgroup>
```

1. User selects `item 1.1` in the list. `item 1.1` is selected as expected.
2. User selects `item 2.1` in the list. Now both `item 1.1` and `item 2.1` are selected.
3. User selects `item 1.2` in the list.  Now `item 1.1` is deselected, while `item 2.1` and `item 1.2` are both selected.

Does that make sense?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thought about using actual radio buttons for this radio button logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#select-box-id optgroup option').click(function() {
    // only affects options contained within the same optgroup
    // and doesn't include this
    $(this).siblings().prop('selected', false);
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Although, truth be told, if you want "radio button logic", you might consider not using a multiple select box.  Usability with multiple select boxes is a pain anyway (people have to ctrl-click to select more than one option).  Consider using radio buttons, or using a single-select box for each group.  Both are harder to mess up.  And they work without JS, which is pretty much always a plus.

Comment: I do appreciate the suggestion, but I'm using a nice [jQuery multiselect plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) that wraps the selectbox in a very nice interface.  That being said - your answer worked! Thanks!

Comment: @UAWDT: The code works, even in FF on Ubuntu.  :P  If it's not working for you, then you're probably using it wrong, and we'll need more details about what's going on.  Is it working in Chrome and IE?  What's it doing instead of what it should be?  Gather that info (and whatever else you can tell us about the problem) and post it in a new question.

Comment: One caveat is that a user can select multiple options by clicking and dragging through multiple options. This solution doesn't handle that (I tried it). I still +1ed it though.

Comment: what should i do if i want to use checkbox instead of label and want to checked only on checkbox in each group

Comment: If you group the related checkboxes together in fieldsets, divs or what have you, then you can do something much like this. Checkboxes almost always have labels beside them, though, and you can't reasonably check a label...so you'll specifically ask for checkboxes in your `siblings()` call.