# Bootstrap: Multiple select fields inside one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to implement a custom select field that has a functionality of several select fields (each one has only one selectable entry). I didn't find any way to merge all the select fields into one, either nor way to allow one selection per form category.

[Here is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bznD6.png)

[Here is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZIng.png)

Example of my current structure:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

 <style>
 .table > tbody > tr > td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:middle;
 }
 .col-xs-2 {
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
 }
 </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">      
      <label for="color" >Color:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="color" >
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      </select>
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">      
      <label for="style">Style:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="style" >
       <option value="square" >Square</option>
       <option value="sphere">Sphere</option>
       </select>
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">      
      <label for="size" >Size:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="size" >
       <option value="tiny">Tiny</option>
       <option value="smallest">Smallest</option>
       <option value="small">Small</option>
       <option value="medium">Medium</option>
       <option value="big">Big</option>
       <option value="biggest">Biggest</option>
       <option value="huge">Huge</option>

       </select>
   </div>   
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update: I found a jQuery plugin that does this for you. It is called **Bootstrap-select**. Check it out here: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

This plugin converts a `<select>` into a Bootstrap Dropdown. One of its features is that you can have a `<select multiple>...</select>` with `<optgroup>`(explained below) and you can set the max number of selections per `<optgroup>` using a `data-max-options` attribute. So you can just set it to 1 for each `<optgroup>`. Here is the documentation for that feature: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#limit-the-number-of-selections

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
        <optgroup label="Color" data-max-options="1">
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Style" data-max-options="1">
            <option value="square" >Square</option>
            <option value="sphere">Sphere</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Size" data-max-options="1">
            <option value="tiny">Tiny</option>
            <option value="smallest">Smallest</option>
            <option value="small">Small</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="big">Big</option>
            <option value="biggest">Biggest</option>
            <option value="huge">Huge</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

---

### Old solution 1:

I think you want to use `<optgroup>`s to contain multiple groups of `<option>`s into one `<select>`. And to make sure you can select more than one option, you need to add the `multiple` Boolean attribute to your `<select>`. However, you still need to make it so you can only select a maximum of one `<option>` per `<optgroup>`. The answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984849/multiselect-box-with-optgroups-select-one-per-group) provides a good piece of javascript code that does that.

Here is a demo that I put together. Hold <kbd>Control</kbd> on your keyboard to select multiple options. Notice that if you try to select another option from the same `<optgroup>`, the previous selection will be de-selected.

```js
$('select optgroup option').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().prop('selected', false);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <select class="form-control" multiple style="width:200px;height:400px;">
        <optgroup label="Color">
            <option>Red</option>
            <option>Green</option>
            <option>Blue</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Style">
            <option>Square</option>
            <option>Sphere</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Size">
            <option value="tiny">Tiny</option>
            <option value="smallest">Smallest</option>
            <option value="small">Small</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="big">Big</option>
            <option value="biggest">Biggest</option>
            <option value="huge">Huge</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

---

### Old solution 2

Here is a new solution that I created using Boostrap's Dropdowns. I created this one since the other solution isn't a dropdown so might not be what you are looking for. Let me know if it works for you.

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function() {
    var groupId = $(this).attr('href');
    $(groupId).val($(this).attr('data-sel'));
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').find('li a[href="'+groupId+'"]').removeClass('bg-success');
    $(this).addClass('bg-success');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li class="dropdown-header">Color</li>
            <li><a href="#color" data-sel="red" class="bg-success">Red</a></li>
            <li><a href="#color" data-sel="green">Green</a></li>
            <li><a href="#color" data-sel="blue">Blue</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Style</li>
            <li><a href="#style" data-sel="square" class="bg-success">Square</a></li>
            <li><a href="#style" data-sel="sphere">Sphere</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Size</li>
            <li><a href="#size" data-sel="tiny" class="bg-success">Tiny</a></li>
            <li><a href="#size" data-sel="smallest">Smallest</a></li>
            <li><a href="#size" data-sel="small">Small</a></li>
            <li><a href="#size" data-sel="medium">Medium</a></li>
            <li><a href="#size" data-sel="big">Big</a></li>
            <li><a href="#size" data-sel="biggest">Biggest</a></li>
            <li><a href="#size" data-sel="huge">Huge</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">      
            <label for="color" >Color:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="color" >
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">      
            <label for="style">Style:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="style" >
                <option value="square" >Square</option>
                <option value="sphere">Sphere</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">      
            <label for="size" >Size:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="size" >
                <option value="tiny">Tiny</option>
                <option value="smallest">Smallest</option>
                <option value="small">Small</option>
                <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="big">Big</option>
                <option value="biggest">Biggest</option>
                <option value="huge">Huge</option>

            </select>
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```